# Could not autowired Object in ItemStreamReader open method

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, reader

I use Spring Batch with Spring Boot and here is a my main class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Here is my configuration classes

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public MyObject getObject() {
        return new MyObject();
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {

    private static final String OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION = null;

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get(Constants.FULL_JOB_NAME)
                .start(stepProcessDocument())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    protected Step stepProcessDocument() {
        return steps.get(Constants.STEP_PROCESS_DOCUMENT_NAME)
            .<Document,Document>chunk(10)
            .reader(buildItemReader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
            .processor(buildItemProcessor())
            .writer(buildItemWriter(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    protected ItemReader<Document> buildItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[" + Constants.PARAM_JOB_PARAMETER + "]}") String param) {
        ItemStreamReader<Document> reader = new CustomItemReader(param);
        reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    protected ItemProcessor<Document, Document> buildItemProcessor() {
        return new CustomItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    protected ItemWriter<Document> buildItemWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters[" + Constants.PARAM_JOB_PARAMETER + "]}") String param) { 
        ItemStreamWriter<Document> writer = new CustomItemWriter(param);
        writer.open(new ExecutionContext());
        return writer;
    }

    @Bean
    public JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor(JobRegistry jobRegistry) {
        JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor = new JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor();
        jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
        return jobRegistryBeanPostProcessor;
    }
}
```

Here is a custom file reader I use in my application.

```
public class CustomItemReader implements ItemStreamReader<Document> {

@Autowired
private MyObject myObject;

private int count = 0;
private String param;

public CustomItemReader(String param) {
    this.param = param;
}

@Override
public void open(ExecutionContext executionContext)
        throws ItemStreamException {
    myObject.open(); //myObject is null
}

@Override
public void update(ExecutionContext executionContext)
        throws ItemStreamException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void close() throws ItemStreamException {
    myObject.close();
}

@Override
public Document read() throws Exception, UnexpectedInputException,
        ParseException, NonTransientResourceException {
    myObject.doStuff();
    count++;
    if(count == 5) {
        return null;
    }
    return new Document();
}
```

I got a Java null pointer exception on myObject.
Why I could not autowired java object in the ItemStreamReader open method?

Comment: How do you load the `Spring` context?

Comment: Can you provide the definition of the `CustomFileReader` as well?

Comment: I suppose I got a -1 because there was not enough informations. I apologize for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. In the definition method of my itemReader :

```
@Bean
@StepScope
protected ItemReader<Document> buildItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[" + Constants.PARAM_JOB_PARAMETER + "]}") String param) {
    ItemStreamReader<Document> reader = new CustomItemReader(param);
    reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
    return reader;
}
```

I execute the method :

```
reader.open(new ExecutionContext());
```

So Each Time I restart a failed job which use this itemReader, I destroy the execution context of the failed job step. and I can't resume where I left off.

To resolve this problem, I have to remove this line of code and to return an ItemStreamReader. thus the framework can access to the open method.

```
@Bean
@StepScope
protected ItemStreamReader<Document> buildItemReader(@Value("#{jobParameters[" + Constants.PARAM_JOB_PARAMETER + "]}") String param) {
    ItemStreamReader<Document> reader = new CustomItemReader(param);
    return reader;
}
```

Moreover, This resolution resolve my original problem too. But unfortunately, I don't know why exactly because I am a beginner in the Spring Framework.

I hope someone will help me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load your Beans as part of your context, since you are using Spring Boot you can use something like this:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // System.exit is common for Batch applications since the exit code can be used to
        // drive a workflow
        System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(
                Application.class, args)));
    }
}
```

The `@ComponentScan` will register all the Spring components like `@Component, @Repository, @Service, @Controller` including `@Configuration` classes. If you need to see a complete example take a look to this project: http://www.codingpedia.org/ama/spring-batch-tutorial-with-spring-boot-and-java-configuration/

I hope this can be helpfull.